# Accessing a custom guard with Auth::user() in Laravel

Tags: laravel

My laravel app has two custom guard which are Admin and Customers.

I have downloaded a package which is a blogging package for my project. The problem however is the package is all setup for Laravel's Auth::user() configuration i.e when I am trying to access blog's admin page, it says I am not authorized even when logged in.

Is there a way I can connect my custom admin guard  Auth::guard('admin')->user() to Auth::user?

Comment: What package you've downloaded?

Comment: Hi it's hessam/laravel-blogger

Comment: I don't see any custom middleware is used in routes there.

Comment: `Auth::...` without `guard(...)` after it means you are using what ever is set as the default guard